# Power BI - Cumulative sum

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to show the cumulative value of a sum of some columns, but I need to merge the cumulative sum with some filters aswell.

I have some filters that can be applied (like City, Department, id, and time period). For example, this code works:

```
Cumulative_sum = CALCULATE( SUM(Table[ColumnA]) + SUM(Table[ColumnB]) + SUM(Table[ColumnC]); FILTER(ALL(Table(TIME_PERIOD); Table[TIME_PERIOD] <= MAX (Table[TIME_PERIOD])))
```

When I tried to add the filter, my coding either returns an error or returns the cumulative sum starting on the time period filtered: For example, let's say I have a value of 10 in January, Feb, March, and April for the city A, department B. If I choose to show the values of March and April, it should show 30 and 40.
However, the current graph shows the cumulative value of the filtered time period (and would show 10 and 20).

Here is what Im trying:

```
   Cumulative_sum = CALCULATE( SUM(TableA[ColumnA]) + SUM(TableA[ColumnB]) + SUM(TableA[ColumnC]); FILTER(ALL(TableB(TIME_PERIOD); TableB[TIME_PERIOD] <= MAX (TableB[TIME_PERIOD])); FILTER(ALLSELECTED(TableA); TableA

[SITUATION] = "OK'))
```

I have tried using the data only from TableA, and tried using TableB as a Time Period table independent. Whats my mistake here?

Comment: Try SUM instead of SUMX

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Cumulative_sum =
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Table[ColumnA]) + SUM(Table[ColumnB]) + SUM(Table[ColumnC]);
        FILTER(ALL(Table);
            Table[TIME_PERIOD] <= MAX(Table[TIME_PERIOD]) &&
            Table[SITUATION] = "OK"
            )
         )
```

The `ALL(Table)` will force the measure to ignore the time period filter.

To keep your additional parameters, you'll probably want to use `ALLEXCEPT`.

```
Cumulative_sum =
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Table[ColumnA]) + SUM(Table[ColumnB]) + SUM(Table[ColumnC]);
        FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(Table, Table[City], Table[Department], Table[ID]);
            Table[TIME_PERIOD] <= MAX(Table[TIME_PERIOD]) &&
            Table[SITUATION] = "OK"
            )
         )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Im having some problems: I cannot use SUM if I'm adding several columns, and I can't use the MAX function as a filter for CALCULATE, thats why I tried with SUMX and FILTER. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: My bad. You need to separate the sums and a `MAX` doesn't work as a simple filter. See my edit.

Comment: I'm not obtaining cumulative results with the solution (it is not adding the values since the beginning of the data until the time period). Perhaps I need to create a new table, I dont know. I will tell if I get any positive results.

Comment: I tought about using the ALLEXPECT() function aswell, but then it seems that I can't control the other filters that need to be applied (department, city). I will try to understand whats happening.

Comment: I tried Cumulative_sum = CALCULATE (
SUM(Table[ColumnA]+Table[ColumnB]+Table[ColumnC]);
ALLEXCEPT(Table, Table[TIME_PERIOD]; FILTER(Table, Table[TIME_PERIOD] <= MAX(Table[TIME_PERIOD]) && Table[SITUATION] = "OK"
)))
but it doesnt provide the cumulative sum aswell

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It's a bit like shooting in the dark when there's nothing to test against.

Comment: Can I upload the file somewhere?

Comment: You could. Google Drive or Dropbox, for example.

Comment: @DanielGutierres See if my edit works. If not, then I'll probably need to see an actual example.

Comment: I have made some tests and understand my problem better now: Cumulative_sum =
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(Table[ColumnA]) + SUM(Table[ColumnB]) + SUM(Table[ColumnC]);
        FILTER(ALL(Table(TIME_PERIOD); Table[TIME_PERIOD] <= MAX (Table[TIME_PERIOD]))) works perfectly. The problem happens when I add the Table[SITUATION] = "OK"